# How to send pdf generated from screen shot in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, pdfmake

**Objective** - Take a screenshot of the page, then make pdf of that and send that pdf to the spring boot backend.

I have implemented the functionality to take the screenshot and convert it into pdf using `html2canvas` and `pdfmake` JavaScript libraries.

**Issue** - I don't know how to send the generated pdf to the backend. I got to know about base64 encode but I am still confused.

**Code** -

```
function takeSS() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 900,
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf"); // to download
        }
    });
}
```

The above code is taking the screenshot of the page converting it to pdf and downloading it.
Instead of downloading it, how can I send this pdf to backend?
Do I need to base64 encode `canvas.toDataURL()`?

**Edit** Changed my code - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChitrangSharma07/pt9sjvka/1/)

Comment: `canvas.toDataURL()` gives the url for the image rendered by the Canvas in base 64 format directly. It Doesnt Give The Data In PDF Format But Rather in Formats Like `png`

Comment: It Looks Something Like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAyCAYAAAAZUZThAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeF7FfQd4G1W69qtqSZbk...........`

Comment: @mrtechtroid so should I need to send this data to the backend directly?  but as you are saying this isn't a pdf so how can I make a pdf and send pdf?

Comment: I Just Clarified that function doesn't give a pdf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs of pdfmake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/client-side/methods/) you're able to get the generated PDF as a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with the [`getBlob`](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/client-side/methods/#get-the-pdf-as-blob) method. The Blob will be a binary representation of your PDF which you can send to your server.

Blobs need to be wrapped inside a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object before they can be sent.

**Edit:** Switch to the latest version [(1.4.1) of html2canvas](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/html2canvas). The older version didn't work properly. The latest versions uses Promises which allows us to use async functions and, in my opinion, makes your code more readable.

The beta version of pdfmake uses Promises instead of a callback function, but [the latest stable version (0.2.5)](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pdfmake/0.2.5) does not. But we can solve this by wrapping the callback with a Promise to still be able to use the async / await syntax.

```
async function takeSS() {
  const canvas = await html2canvas(document.body);
  const data = canvas.toDataURL();
  const docDefinition = {
    content: [{
      image: data,
      width: 900,
    }]
  };
  
  const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
  const blob = await new Promise(resolve => {
    pdfDocGenerator.getBlob(resolve);
  });
  
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('pdf', blob, 'test.pdf');
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch('myapi-url', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    });
    
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('POST request failed');
    }

    const message = await response.text();
    console.log(message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I have one question here I tried running the code but it is not giving blob also fetch api is not getting called.

Comment: Okay. So you're saying that `getBlob` is not getting called? Are there any errors in the console? And the **network** tab of your browser is not showing any XHR requests?

Comment: Yes getBlob is not getting called I tried get getStream and getBuffer as well from docs but its not working.
No there is no error in the console also I tried to call api nothing in the networks tab as well

Comment: I have added jsFiddle of my code.

Comment: Then it's probably a different problem. If they are not producing an error or result then they are never reached. I've looked into the docs of html2canvas and see that you're using an older *way* of using it. The latest version uses an implementation with Promises [see example](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started)

Comment: It seems that the docs of pdfMake are also not up to date. Give me a minute, i'll work something out.

Comment: I changed my function to use Promises in html2canvas function, I checked I was using the latest 3. version of pdfMake which is under development. But I am not able to find any CDN link of the version 1 or 2.

Comment: Good call, I've included links to the 0.2.5 version of pdfmake in the answer, as well  modified code for the `getBlob` method. There is always a way. :)

Comment: Thank you soo much for all the help :) I am grateful to you